# ffmpeg and Red5 Issue: Increase in number of ffmpeg simultaneous streams to Red5 resulting in packet loss

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, rtmp, red5, flv

I have a screen sharing app written in flex, using which one person can share his screen with another person via Red5 server (Version: 1.0.3). Platform is Windows Server 2008. Now, I want to load test this Red 5 server to find out maximum how many simultaneous screen sharing session it can allow, without any quality compromise. By quality I mean, speed of transmission and no data loss during transmission. I simulated the load using ffmpeg command.

For this, instead of transmitting a live captured screen, I am transmitting (uploading) a FLV file stored in my local to the Red5 server using ffmpeg command. In the receiving client side, I am starting to download (transmitting) this same FLV file after 5 secs since the upload has started. This is working fine when I am running this test for less than 10 pairs of upstreaming-downstreaming sessions. But, when the number is increasing beyond 10, I am observing significant packet loss in transmission.

Here are the commands I am running in a loop. The loop count is the number of streaming pairs.

1. upstreaming: `ffmpeg -re -i <file_name1> -f flv -ar 22050 "rtmp://<stream_name>" -report`
2. downstreaming: `ffmpeg -re -i "rtmp://<stream_name> live=1" <file_name2> -report`

The  and  are set in such a way, that in the downstream I will download the same uploaded file. "rtmp://" are the same in both the cases. I am not doing the upstream in record mode, hence, no physical file is getting saved in the server side. When I am analyzing the file I received in the receiving client side, it is a poor quality video due to frame loss. Uploading and downloading machines are two different machines. I ran the test for many hours, repeating the same 10 simultaneous streaming sets. Each set is consistently giving the same results.

What is puzzling me is, this is working fine without any packet loss for less that 10 simultaneous streaming. I searched about it in various forums, but none of the answers were applicable for this scenario. For a while I was thinking that Red5 has limited capacity, but I found many posts saying Red5 can easily scale up to take very big load. Does that mean, the problem is in my configuration? I am not sure which are to focus on.

An example log snippet:

Lots of missing data at downstream side. For e.g. between frames 101 and 102 there is a difference of 25 sec. On replaying the video there is a stoppage for this much time.In this time gap all the frames are lost.

```
frame=  101 fps=1.0 q=14.5 size=    2650kB time=00:01:41.00 bitrate= 214.9kbits/s
frame=  102 fps=1.0 q=13.2 size=    2763kB time=00:02:06.00 bitrate= 179.6kbits/s
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: less than 10 works fine? do you get ffmpeg error log messages? full console and command line output?

Comment: Is it a local red5 or remote? You could be saturating your nic.

Comment: It is remote Red5. What do you mean by nic? Network bandwidth? I have updated the question with a log snippet. Please check.

Comment: Also, does the screen share recording format (fps, CODEC, buffering, etc) matters to avoid or reduce frame loss?